# Determinacy and uniformization

Tags: logic, reference-request, set-theory, descriptive-set-theory

It's known that $PD$ implies projective uniformization. Assuming $AD$, is there an analogous theorem that holds for all subsets of the plane (where the uniformizing functions are reasonably definable for whatever interpretation of "reasonably definable" that makes the theorem interesting)? If the answer is negative, then what are the strongest known uniformization results that follow from $AD$?

Comment: Yes, there are many results along these lines. The theory $\mathsf{AD}^+$ implies that the class of $\Sigma^2_1$ sets has the scale property. In many cases this is best possible (for instance, in $L(\mathbb R)$). You can get uniformization of larger pointclasses in strong models of determinacy. (In particular, $\mathsf{AD}_{\mathbb R}$ gives you uniformization for all sets.)

Comment: @AndrésCaicedo For the purpose of the result that I'm trying to prove, I'm particularly interested in the case of $AD$ without additional hypotheses (it would also be interesting for me to know when and why uniformization (for all sets) fails in models of $AD$).

Comment: What specifically are you after? Maybe knowing some of the context may help. In any case, from what I wrote, $\mathsf{AD}$ gives you uniformization for boldface $(\Sigma^2_1)^{L({\mathbb R})}$. That this is best possible is a theorem of Solovay, essentially a diagonal argument. All of this is explained in reasonable detail in Kanamori's book. For a more extensive and detailed treatment, look at volume 1 of the (reissued) Cabal Seminar.